# Bound on derivative in space of continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

Let $C_0^1[0,\pi] $ be the usual space of continuously differentiable functions which vanish at the endpoints of given interval. Let $||u||$ denote usual norm of $u$.

Does
$ ||u||< \epsilon$ for given $\epsilon >0$ imply $|u'(x)|<1, \ \ \forall x \in [0,\pi]?$

Could one prove this statement or give counter - example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a norm, if $\forall \epsilon >0:\:\|u\|<\epsilon$ then $\|u\|=0$ which means $u=0$ and certainly $u'(x)=0<1 \:\forall x\in[0,\pi]$.

This brings me to ask - what is the usual norm? Are we talking about an actual norm or just a semi-norm?

**For the modified question:**

Take some $u\in C_{0}^{1}[0,\pi]$ with $|u'(x)|\geq 1$ for some $x\in[0,\pi]$, in particular $u\not=0$. Take $\epsilon=2\|u\|>0$. While $\|u\|<\epsilon$ holds, $|u'(x)|<1$ certainly does not hold.

Comment: I have "slightly" edited my question - there was a typo in quantifier. Does it hold right now ? Usual norm is $|| u || = \sup\  |u| + sup\ | u'|$, where supremum is taken over given interval.

Comment: This is the Sobolev norm, which not always is the "usual" one. See my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

If $\epsilon \le 1$ then yes, because $|u'(x)| \le \sup |u| \le \|u\|_{C^1}$.

If $\epsilon > 1$ then no: consider functions of the form $u(x) = C\sin(kx)$ with $k\in \mathbb N$. These have $\sup |u| = C$ and $\sup |u'| = Ck$, so $\|u\| = C(1+k)$. Choosing $k$ to be very large and $C$ correspondingly small allows us to get $|u'|$ arbitrarily close to $\epsilon$ while maintaining $\| u \| < \epsilon$.